# Cannot get button to display in IE 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I have a button created like so:

```
<div id = "userForgot">
<!-- Back button used -->
<button id = "forgotGoBack" onclick = "backToPage()" >< Back</button>
<!-- Form used to submit all membership info to be used on server -->
<form id = "ForgotForm" action = "/" onclick = "formURL(this)" method = "post" >
```

I cannot get it to show up on IE 7. This is the only item that will not display. I can locate the button (if I scroll over where it should be I get a pointer, and if I click where it should be it works. Here is my `css` that is used for all but IE 7:

```
 /*
  * The back button for the page
  */
 #forgotGoBack
 {
     z-index: 500;
     color: #fbfbfb;
     font-family: Arial;
     font-size: 11px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 400px;
     left: 305px;
     border: 0;
     padding: 0;
     background-color: transparent;    
 }
    #forgotGoBack:hover
    {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Here is my code I use for IE 7 Only through this command:

`<!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/DefaultStyleForIE7.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"/><![endif]-->`

```
/* Made back button visible */
#forgotGoBack
{
    z-index: 300;
    position: relative;
    color: Red;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;   
    display: block;
}
```

I made the `color` red because it would stick out on my page and I could see it easier. I also tried to move it to a different position with the `left` and `top` calls. I tried to use a `position: relative` call because I read that in some cases it fixes IE 7 issues like I am having. Regardless of the `css` I add to the IE 7 code the button will not move. I have also added code to the `div` holding the button in hopes that was the issue.

`#userForgot
{
    z-index: 200;
}`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a sibling float, it will be hidden. Try wrapping a div around the button and it should magically auto-appear. Don't give the div any styles.

Otherwise, can you post all the markup around it?

Comment: The only other items on the page are nested inside a `form`. I edited the `html` section of my question to contain that `form`. There is no `css` on that `form` either

Comment: Also I wrapped in in a `div` and that did not fix the issue